# Including views from a different table into an advertisement select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains advertisement info, and a table that contains views for advertisements. The table with views contains an ip and an advertisement id, and it updates every time an ad is requested.

```
SELECT ip FROM view WHERE adId = ?; // I only get the count
SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM view WHERE adId = ?; // I only get the count
SELECT * FROM advertisements;
```

Right now, I run all 3 of those queries in order to generate a response. Is there a way to combine them into one?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are worth a thousand words -- or more.

Comment: I'm with Gordon here. We don't need a thousand words of description. We do need a schema and some sample data, a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: I simplified the question.

Comment: But not in the way requested. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if advertisement table has the column adId as well or it's corresponding column, you can connect the two tables using that key. you can have a query something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.ip,
       a.*
  FROM `view` v
  JOIN advertisement a
    ON v.adId = a.adId
 WHERE v.adId = ?
```

With your comment below, you can use the following query to get the counts you need for each advertisement.

```
SELECT adId,
       COUNT(ip),
       COUNT(DISTINCT ip)
  FROM `view`
 WHERE adId = ? --you can ommit this to see all advertisements
 GROUP BY adId
```

if you want to see the detail information of the advertisement, you can connect the query to advertisement table.

Comment: My bad, when shortening my question, I removed a crucial part. From the first two queries, I only get the count. I'm not trying to connect a single entry from view with a single entry from advertisement. I'm trying to get an ip count and an ip distinct count for every advertisement. The view table does contain the advertisement id along with an ip. Thats the way I thought of to keep all views and unique views for every advertisement. If I  can't get them in a single query, I might have to think of another way.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!